# CSS: Clear othe styles in Live Preview

Tags: jquery, css

I have a `div` LivePreview that previews the text entered into a textarea as HTML using jQuery.  The problem is, it inherits all the other styles on the page, as it should...

Is there a way to clear all styles for just the LivePreview (`table`, `p`, etc...) or will I have to reset each of the LivePreview children manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to do it is as done in [`jsfiddle`](http://www.jsfiddle.net) itself which does a similar thing to what you want. The way they seem to have doe it is put that box within an `iframe`.

Anything nested within the `iframe` loses any CSS that has been called out of it unless the CSS file is explicitly linked to from within the `iframe. So your code should be:

```
<div class="LivePreview">
    <iframe>
        <head></head>
        <body>
            /* Any HTML you want and will have the default CSS*/
        </body>
    </iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks nayish, i looked at some of their source, and got a few ideas from it...not going to be as complicated, but probably the best and quickest solution for what I'm trying to achieve.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could, at the beginning of the CSS file, add:

```
*#LivePreview {
   margin: 0px;
   padding: 0px;
   /*Any styles that might otherwise be overwritten*/
}

*#LivePreview * { }
```

Anything specified by id "livepreview" *should* have only those styles associated, nothing inherited.

Comment: This would not work, an `a` tag nested in this that lost it's hover color for example would not get it back using this.

Comment: Which shouldn't be a problem if you're trying to clear *all* styles within live preview.

Comment: it is since you're not clearing that specific style... I understood clearing to returning to the default

Comment: Right, I want basically a whole new stylesheet that reflects the front end of the web app, as opposed to styling it like the backend...

Comment: It's really no different than setting the defaults per CSS Reset. Force inheritance of nothing upon all children.

Comment: I see. In that case, duplicate your CSS from the front end, and make each element a child of livepreview